# Как сжать изображение numpy(array) и cv2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Мне нужна помощь со сжатием получаемого изображения:
img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor));
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY). Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? Мне нужно его сжимать что бы тратить меньше врмемени на передачу и открытие.

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy


with mss.mss() as sct:
     monitor = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1000, 'height': 1000}

    for _ in range(100000000):
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', img)
        cv2.waitKey(20)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break'
```

Comment: Читайте про алгоритмы сжатия. Один из самых простых: заменить последовательные вхождения одинаковых элементов на элемент + количество повторений

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html, по идее этот способ сжимает же изображение?

Comment: алгоритмы из zlib, gzip и так далее сжимают любые файлы, не только изображения

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед? [используйте JPEG и пересылайте данные по частям](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994937/send-image-using-socket-programming-python)

Comment: Просто я уже написал для этого код...

Comment: Кстати, Вася, вы видели код сервера и клиента, как вы считает есть ли смысл отправлять массив по частям?

Comment: @MaxU JPEG всё-таки обычно это алгоритм с потерей данных, что не всегда приемлемо. )

Comment: @CrazyElf, здесь речь идёт о скриншотах - по-моему как раз будет

Comment: Я почему то не вижу разницы между не сжатой и сжатой картинкой на девятом уровне. Или это именно я не вижу, а она есть?